# Difference between Deprecate and retract?

Tags: go, go-modules

Today I upgraded to Go 1.17. The release notes at https://golang.org/doc/go1.17 talk about this new feature:

> Module authors may deprecate a module by adding a // Deprecated: comment to go.mod

I know from Go 1.16 that go.mod file can specify a `retract` directive and retract a module version, or more versions.

The usage of the new `// Deprecated` comment is similar to `retract`. Please can you formally explain when I should use `// Deprecate` and when `retract`?

Comment: To over-summarize: "retract" = "do not use, now or ever"; "deprecate" = "do not use tomorrow".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `// Deprecated: comment` to indicate you don't support a **major** version anymore. For example you released `v2.0.0`, and you don't intend to work on `v1.0.0` anymore. `v1.0.0` may still work as intended, but it may lack many new features you only intend to add to `v2.0.0`.

`retract` can be used to mark a minor or patch version (or a range of versions enclosed in `[ ]`) that may contain a severe bug or vulnerability and they should not be used. For example you may release `v1.2.0` and 2 days later someone discovers a security vulnerability in it. You may modify `go.mod` to add `retract` to version `v1.2.0`, and mark this addition as `v1.2.1`:

```
retract (
    v1.2.0 // Security vulnerability discovered.
    v1.2.1 // Contains retractions only.
    [v3.0.0, v3.9.9] // Retract all from v3
)
```

This will inform the `go` tool not to upgrade to `v1.2.0` nor to `v1.2.1` (e.g. when you instruct to update to the latest version with `go get example.com/m@latest`). When you fixed the issue and release `v1.2.2`, `go get example.com/m@latest` will update to `v1.2.2`.

---

Quoting from [Go Modules Reference: Deprecation:](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-module-deprecation)

> Deprecation messages are intended to inform users that the module is no longer supported and to provide migration instructions, for example, to the latest major version. Individual minor and patch versions cannot be deprecated; [`retract`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract) may be more appropriate for that.

And quoting from [`retract` directive:](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract)

> A `retract` directive indicates that a version or range of versions of the module defined by `go.mod` should not be depended upon. A `retract` directive is useful when a version was published prematurely or a severe problem was discovered after the version was published. Retracted versions should remain available in version control repositories and on [module proxies](https://golang.org/ref/mod#glos-module-proxy) to ensure that builds that depend on them are not broken.

Comment: Yes: you may _both_ deprecate _and_ retract all versions of a module, if you want to communicate both “prefer a different module” (deprecate) and “do not add dependencies on any existing version of this module” (retract). That said, retracting every release of a module probably suffices: “do not add dependencies on any version of this module” necessarily _implies_ “prefer a different module”.